# What is the equivalent of a break statement for a PHP class?

Tags: php, oop, class

I use `die()` for error output in a class in PHP.

I sometimes call this class from another class.  When the first class dies, I don't want it to kill the class that called it.  I think a `break()` statement within a loop is a good analogy, but instead, I'm looking to break a class from within itself.

Is there a way to confine `die()` to the class that called it, or is there a preferred way to get this behavior?

Answer (score 4):

Never `die()` in a class

You can use `return`, and return an error message, false, etc. Or you can throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Galen is right. But I'd go further:

Never use `die()` for error reporting. Throw an [exception](http://us.php.net/exceptions) - uncaught exceptions get sent to the PHP error log. Or use [`error_log`](http://php.net/error_log) in conjunction with a custom error/exception [handler](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php). Emit proper HTTP headers (500, 404, etc.). Show users a pretty error page.